# Setting up Extended WPF Toolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I'm trying to get Extended WPF Toolkit working in Visual Studio but I'm having difficulties following the short guide on their website:
http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/610794

I've installed it via NuGet and when I right click into the toolbox and try to enable some of the new elements, I can see their are already enabled. They do not however appear in the toolbox itself.

Adding a using statement doesn't give me an error, so VS seems to recognize it.

I suspect it has something to do with XAML files.

> 7. Add a new xmlns (for example,
>      xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit") to the top of
>      XAML files In your XAML, use the namespace prefix (in the above
>      example, )
> 8. In your XAML, use the namespace prefix (in the above example, )

I really have no idea what to make of this. I'm not even sure if I have any XAML files. Sorry if this question is really trivial, but I'm fairly new to VS and coding in general.

Comment: When you're doing WPF, you've got XAML. Make sure you Rebuild properly.Maybe the toolbox isn't supported, not a big loss.

Comment: Is there a way to somehow bring up that XAML so I can edit it?

Comment: It's usually in a split-view with the designer. Maybe you closed that part.

Comment: I probably did. You wouldn't happen to know how I could bring it back up again, would you?

Comment: There should be 3 buttons in the bottom right of the forms designer.

Comment: Apparently I'm blind. I can't find these buttons anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You have to manually add them - right click in the Toolbox menu, then add a new tab for WPF Extended Toolkit, then select "Choose Items...", select the WPF Components tab & browse to the DLL that you installed (mine was installed to packages\Extended.Wpf.Toolkit.2.3\lib\net40 in the application folder).

Comment: Like I wrote in the OP, I did that and they seem to be already enabled and added. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with XAML and XMLNS.

Comment: Then I am not sure what you mean by _"they seem to be already enabled and added"_ but _"They do not however appear in the toolbox itself"_. When I first installed the toolkit, the components did not appear in the toolbox - but I could manually add them to my solution (so they were _added & enabled_), to get them displayed in the toolbox I used the above procedure.

Comment: The options are there. Any they are enabled. The boxes are ticked. But the new elements don't appear in the toolbox list, so I can't add them to my Form. I'm not sure how to explain it differently.

Comment: So when you say "the options are there" - which options are you referring to? Which boxes are ticked?

Comment: So I'm at Form, the Toolbox is displaying all sorts of stuff I can add (like Textboxes, etc...). From here I do the following.
Right click into the Toolbox -> choose Elements -> WPF-Components. The stuff that I need is ticked.

Comment: I understand now - that worked on my application without any problem. Have you tried creating a new tab and adding them there. Possibly unchecking them first before you add to the new tab. On the WPF Components tab - is everything with namespace Xceed.WPF.Toolkit.* selected?

Comment: I just tried doing that. When I unchecked the tools that I needed, they disappeard. Tried reinstalling the library to no avail. How can something so simple be so fiddly? What the hell?

Comment: I find the package a bit of a pain myself - the components regularly disappear from the Toolbox & I have to add them back again. The components themselves work fine though - I have never had any problems even when they disappear from the Toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, 
You need to set xmlns (xml namespace) as

xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit" in `<Window>` tag

and then build your program to resolve all dependencies.

Later use `<xctk:>` tag..

Comment: I think that might actually be the solution. Where could I add this line of code?

Comment: Add the code in <Window> tag, I have added a snap shot of my solution, but the trick is it rebuild the solution once you have added the xmlns.:.  <Window x:Class="filter3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:l="clr-namespace:filter3"
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="525">

Comment: Yesterday I found out I wasn't even working with WPF. I was working with Winforms. Sorry you wasted your time typing that out. I would have deleted this question but this site won't let me.